# Shortcut/Menu item for testing a form @ design time

Tags: visual-studio

When you create a Windows Desktop Application/C++ in VS, you can test temporarily a dialog under the resource editor at design time through Ctrl+T. For exmaple, you can check if the tab order is right.

I created a Windows Forms App/C# and under the resource editor I would like to test the form at design time, but I couldn't find the shortcut/menu item.
Is that possible?
.